# How to query jpa entity in JOINED inheritance, without creating table for same?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I am trying to implemet inheritance hierarchy as mentioned in below image using hibernate Joined strategy.

Since Joined strategy creates table for entity regardless of entity class is Concrete or Abstract.

I don't want to create separate table for "CompanyEmployee" so I declared it as mapped superclass, but I should able to query this class/subclasses in polymorphic way.

Since it is mapped superclass I can't do this, and if I declare it to be entity it will create table which I want to avoid.

So, is there any way I can achieve this? I am thinking about mixed inheritance but from below quote it doesn't seems to be a good solution.

> **Mixed Inheritance**
>
> We should begin this section by saying that the practice of mixing inheritance types within a single
> inheritance hierarchy is currently outside the specification. We are including it because it is both useful
> and interesting, but we are offering a warning that it might not be portable to rely on such behavior,
> even if your vendor supports it.

[Inheritance hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbOtL.png)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="j_employee")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) 
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="emp_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class JEmployee extends AuditLog implements Serializable {

@Id
@Basic
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="employee_id")
private Integer employeeId;

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="join_date")
private Date joinDate;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="person_id", nullable=false)
private Person person;

@Column(name="emp_type", updatable=false, insertable=false)
private String empType;


//Getters and Setters
}




@Entity
@Table(name="j_contract_employee")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="JContractEmployee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="contract_employee_id", referencedColumnName="employee_id")
public class JContractEmployee extends JEmployee implements Serializable {

@Basic
@Column(name="daily_rate")
private Integer dailyRate;

@Basic
@Column(name="term")
private Integer term;

//Getters and Setters
}


//Don't want to create table for this class, but I should able to query this clas/subclasses in polymorphic way
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class JCompanyEmployee extends JEmployee implements Serializable {

@Basic
@Column(name="vacation")
private Integer vacation;

//Getters and Setters
public Integer getVacation() {
    return vacation;
}

public void setVacation(Integer vacation) {
    this.vacation = vacation;
}
}



@Entity
@Table(name="j_part_time_employee")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="JPartTimeEmployee")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="part_time_employee_id", referencedColumnName="employee_id")
public class JPartTimeEmployee extends JCompanyEmployee implements Serializable {

@Basic
@Column(name="hourly_rate")
private Integer hourlyRate;

//Getters and Setters 
}



@Entity
@Table(name="j_full_time_employee")
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@DiscriminatorValue(value="JFullTimeEmployee")
public class JFullTimeEmployee extends JCompanyEmployee implements Serializable {

@Basic
@Column(name="salary")
private Integer salary;

@Basic
@Column(name="penion")
private Integer pension;

//Getters and Setter
}
```

Comment: Declaring something as `@MappedSuperclass` shouldn't stop that having a table, since the fields of that class need persisting, and you have chosen JOINED. The JPA spec doesn't say it it will not create a table in that situation ... where do you expect those fields to be persisted?!

Comment: I expect fields of JCompanyEmployee i.e MappedSuperClass to be persistent fields of it's subclasses. So, In above sample code  fields of  MapedSuperClass are persistent in in it's subclass JFullTimeEmployee and JPartTimeEmployee. But what I am seeking is how I can query JCompanyEmployee and it's subclasses in polymorphic way as we can so with JEmployee class? Since it is mapped superclass, java spec says that you can not query on that class, and if I declare it to be an entity it joined strategy will create table for that class which I don't want.

Comment: Your first assumption is not correct / portable, since there is nothing that requires that in the spec. As for your second, some JPA providers do allow querying of `@MappedSuperclass` (DataNucleus is one example) but again not portable. You'll have to change your expectations